# DynamoDB stream to elasticsearch for multi-api

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, aws-elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb-streams

guys

- I need your help to know, what's the best practice for a multi-api scenario to index data to elasticsearch.

I have for example:

1.users api
2.produts api

But because of any of the apis, triggers the stream, my question is how come can I know where the request api comes from and the http method, because if I need to update username and email only and not the user item complete, but because the stream does know is an update and what's the PK or SK but don't know what http method is, or what field to update.

Example:

New user: {
index: db
id: user#19201,
name: username,
email: user@email.com,
age: 18,
country:US,
...
}

update:
{
index: db
id: user#19201,
name: username,
email: user@email.com
}

the stream will override the record complete for the new update.

- in another hand the products api, can be only be indexed by the same index as user api "db" because of the same issue the stream does not now what endpoint is to index it, that's why a fixed one will work, but a multi index won't work

thanks for your any helpful comment.

Comment: What is indexing the DynamoDB items into Elasticsearch? Is it a custom Lambda function that you have written, is it the AWS-supplied `dynamodb-to-elasticsearch` Lambda blueprint, or is it something else?

Comment: it was just a expression, what it means every time the trigger will add, update or delete in elastichsearch with dynamoDB data, using the stream

Comment: Not sure I understand. I'm asking what mechanism you are using, or have built, that takes the DynamoDB Streams data and inserts/updates Elasticsearch.

Comment: from the dynamoDB stream which is a lambda function, takes the ouput data generate from event from dynamoDB, and using aws-sdk nodejs add,update,delete the elasticsearch data, but because of stream,does not know what to update if only one field, or overwrite or apply a different index for each api like user and products to no mix it.

Comment: When your Lambda function sees a MODIFY event, it includes the item's key and the modified attributes. Elasticsearch supports partial document updates. Just identify the Elasticsearch document associated with the item (you must already have a way to do this) and submit a partial update. I don't understand the problem you're having related to two indexes so it may be worth updating your post with a concrete example.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot, using document updates will update any field, about indexing I don't know its a good practice to use the same index for all dynamoDB data at elasticsearch as example "db" above, instead of having an index for api or entity like products and users for searching performance and data separation

Comment: Either way, you need to be able to identify the documents independently (either because they are stored in different ES indexes or because each document has a type field).

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot, I will do the task to identify each index and attributes to update. :)